# Sidenav and toolbar not appearing in new component in angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to use mat toolbar and side nav in my angular application. I have a component called app-layout which has both toolbar and side nav, here is the code,

```
<div class="yaanapage">
  <mat-toolbar color="primary" class="toolbar">
  <button mat-icon-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()"><mat-icon>menu</mat-icon></button>
  <span>YAANA-</span>
  </mat-toolbar>

  <mat-sidenav-container fullscreen  autosize style="top: 80px !important;">
    <mat-sidenav #sidenav mode="push" opened="false" class="sideNav">
      <mat-nav-list>
        <mat-list-item (click)="onDashboardClicked()">Dashboard</mat-list-item>
        <a><mat-list-item>Incidents</mat-list-item></a>
        <a><mat-list-item>Users</mat-list-item></a>
    </mat-nav-list>
    </mat-sidenav>
    <mat-sidenav-content >
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
  </mat-sidenav-container>
  </div>
```

It displays the toolbar and side nav, now on side nav, I have different components namely dashboard, users etc.
Now when I click on dashboard, the dashboard view is replaced in   . But it is not happening like that, the complete side nav and toolbar are not getting displayed, only dashboard view is displayed.
The dashboard view is,

```
<mat-form-field>
   <mat-select placeholder="Choose location" (change)="onChange($event)" (ngModel)="yaanaServiceLocations">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let location of yaanaServiceLocations" [value]="location">
      {{ location.areaName }}
    </mat-option>
   </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
    <agm-map [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="longitude" [zoom]="zoom">
        <agm-marker *ngFor="let marker of coordinates; let i = index" 
        [iconUrl]="icon" 
        [latitude]="marker.latitude" 
        [longitude]="marker.longitude"
        [markerClickable]="true"
        (markerClick)="markerClicked(marker.latitude,marker.longitude)">
        <agm-snazzy-info-window [closeWhenOthersOpen]="true" [maxHeight]="300" [maxWidth]="1400"
        [backgroundColor]="'orange'" [padding]="'20px'">
          <ng-template>
            <mat-card>{{ pLocationId }}  {{ pLocationName }}</mat-card><br/>
              <mat-grid-list cols="12" rowHeight="100px" (ngModel)="pCycle">
                <mat-grid-tile [colspan]="4" [rowspan]="2" *ngFor="let cycle of pCycle; let i = index" [style.background]="orange"
                [style.padding-right]="'50px'" [style.background]="'white'">
                    <mat-grid-tile-header [style.height]="20">{{i+1}}</mat-grid-tile-header>
                  <div [style.background]="orange">
                    <i class="material-icons">motorcycle</i>
                    <span [style.color]="white" >{{cycle.qrCode}}</span><br/>
                    <br/>
                    <i class="material-icons">battery_alert</i>
                    <span>{{ cycle.batteryLevel }}</span>

                  </div>
                  <mat-grid-tile-footer [style.background]="yellow">
                    <button mat-mini-fab (click)="showDirection(cycle.latitude, cycle.longitude)">
                      <mat-icon>navigation</mat-icon>
                    </button>
                  </mat-grid-tile-footer>
                </mat-grid-tile>
                </mat-grid-list>
          </ng-template>

        </agm-snazzy-info-window>
        <agm-direction *ngIf="dir" [origin]="dir.origin" [destination]="dir.destination" [visible]="show"></agm-direction>
    </agm-marker>
    <div ng-show="showInfo" class="InfoWindow">
        <h2> I am InfoWindow</h2>
      </div>
    </agm-map>
```

The routing module has the following code,

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent},
  {
    path: 'applayout', component: AppLayoutComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: false })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

app.component.html

```
<div [class]="theme">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Please correct me to display both toolbar and side nav in new components also.

Answer (score 1):

There is two options.(Most Preferable 2 option)

**1)** You have to create one master page where your applayout will be rendered like this.

In your master page (if you don't have a master page then put it into appcomponent file for more information please check [angular.io](http://angular.io))

```
<applayout>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
</applayout>
```

Now your dashboard Page will render between applayout so you will have both applayout view and dashboard view in the same page.

**2)** Other than this you can also do one thing that put your applayout code in appcomponent files and where ever you want to render your dashboard page put their router-outlet tag. by that, you can easily render your dashboard view with side nav and toolbar

In my project I have done like this::

**app.component.html**

```
<div class="container">
    <nav class='navbar navbar-inverse'>
         <div class='container-fluid'>
           <ul class='nav navbar-nav'>
             <li><a [routerLink]="['home']">Home</a></li>
             <li><a [routerLink]="['books']">Book List</a></li>
             <li><a [routerLink]="['todoList']">ToDo</a></li>
             <li><a [routerLink]="['blogs']">Live Blogs</a></li>
           </ul>
           <!-- <ul *ngIf="username" class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right'>
             <li style='float:right;'><a (click)="logout()">Logout</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul *ngIf="!username" class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right'>
             <li style='float:right;'><a [routerLink]="['login']">LogIn</a></li>
          </ul> -->
          <ul *ngIf="id" class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right'>
            <li style='float:right;'><a (click)="logout()">LogOut</a></li>
            <li style='float:right;'><a [routerLink]="['profile']">Profile</a></li>
         </ul>
          <ul *ngIf="!id" class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right'>
            <li style='float:right;'><a [routerLink]="['login']">LogIn</a></li>
            <li style='float:right;'><a [routerLink]="['register']">Register</a></li>
         </ul> 
        </div>
   </nav>    
  <div class='container'>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Between `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` my other component will be load so if you want your sidenav in all the pages then use it like this.

Comment: Please explain me with the example?

Comment: I edited my answer with example that i use in my project.

Comment: When i use the technique I am getting the same view getting displayed twice, here is the image of the output I am getting, https://ibb.co/hK7toc         and here is the html code `<div class="container">
    <mat-toolbar color="primary" class="toolbar">
        <button mat-icon-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()"><mat-icon>menu</mat-icon></button>
        <span>Hello</span>
    </mat-toolbar>
    <div class="container">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
</div>`

Comment: Can you provide me plunkr ?